How can I semantically validate a YAML schema?
I am working with Aerospike, and I want to create a script that will allow me to validate the aerospike configurations.
I am able to validate the syntax of the files using asconfig validate command.
Now, I want to go up one level, and want to validate the config file with my own schema. For example, I want to make sure that the value for replication-factor is always greater than 3 in the config file. The issue is that the replication-factor parameter is stored within multiple parameters.
namespace test {
        replication-factor 2

        storage-engine memory {
                data-size 4G
        }
}

My current solution is to convert the config file to a yaml file, and then use a yaml parser to compare the two files.
I have tried a few yaml parsers, but they can only parse specific values from the yaml file but fail to validate schema with the yaml file. Any way I can achieve is more easily?
I tried asconfig convert -a 7.0.0 to convert the config file into .yaml format.
And to validate the config file for version 7.0.0, I ran asconfig validate -a 7.0.0 <file>
Edit:
namespaces:
    - name: test
      replication-factor: 2
      storage-engine:
        data-size: 4294967296
        type: memory
    - name: bar
      replication-factor: 2
      storage-engine:
        data-size: 4294967296
        type: memory

The replication-factor for namespace test is 4 while for bar it is 2.

What were your problems with YAML parsers? Can you describe in more detail why this didn't work for you?

@flyx I'm not able to understand what will be the best practice to parse a parameter which is nested inside another parameter. And also, there could be similar parameters nested similarly, but under different parameters. Please see the question, I've edited it to include an example of the config file.

A YAML parser will parse the whole structure, giving you access to exactly the information you're seeking („where in the structure is this value located?“). What did you do that did not have this information available?

Yes, I'm now using PyYaml module to load the yaml data, and then combinations of if-else to validate the parameters, including the nested ones. As of now, this is the only way I could think of.

If that works for you, what's your question? How to do it simpler? It's probably somewhat easier to use a bash script with some yq commands that do the relevant queries but generally, schema checking is just a bunch of if-else checks.

I don't know of any parsing solution that would be any easier than what has already been mentioned in the comments, but if you have experience with Go, you could build your own version of asconfig.
The schema files are here and asconfig is here.
use git clone --recurse-submodules to clone the asconfig repo and it will include the schemas.
You can edit the schema for your version to conform to whatever valid setup you're looking for, then build a local version of asconfig to use that schema.
